# Passing on values in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action

I have a `signup.jsp` page where a new user enters his email id. A snippet of this page is as shown:

```
<s:form action="signupprocess">
        <s:textfield label="E-Mail" key="userid"></s:textfield>
        <s:password label="Password" key="password" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:password>
        <s:password label="Retype Passowrd" key="repass" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:password>
        <s:submit cssStyle="margin-top:5px;" />
        </s:form>
```

Now after all the backend process is done i.e. adding the user's email and password to the database the user is directed to "user.jsp" where he has to fill out the personal details. This page is as shown:

```
<s:form action="user_details">
                    <s:textfield label="First Name" key="firstname"></s:textfield>
                    <s:textfield label="Last Name" key="lastname" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:label label="Adress" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:label>
                    <s:textfield label="Line1" key="addr_1" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:textfield label="Line2" key="addr_2" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:textfield label="Line3" key="addr_3" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:textfield label="City" key="city" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:textfield label="State" key="state" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:textfield label="Mobile" key="mobile" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:textfield>
                    <s:checkboxlist list="areas" name="userareas" label="Areas of Interest" cssStyle="margin-top:5px;"></s:checkboxlist>
                    <s:submit cssStyle="margin-top:10px;" />
                    </s:form>
```

Now in this jsp's action class I want to have access to the specific user's email id so that entries are made in the database in that user's row only. How can I access userid's value from signup.jsp page in user.jsp's action class.

I can provide any further information if required.

Comment: You can in many different ways, what a specific problem you have?

Comment: @RomanC My specific problem is this: PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update user set first_name=?,last_name=?,address=?,mobile=? where email=? "); So I want the value for the last '?' from signup.jsp

Comment: @RomanC Is it clear from the comment or should I do edits in my question?

Comment: you can store the value in session in signup.jsp's action class and retrieve in user.jsp's action class

Comment: @Arkantos A session is created in my application only  when user logs in and not just when he signs up. So any other solution?

Comment: I'm talking about HttpSession which will persist between multiple requests from the same user, doesn't have to a be login session. In fact, there's no login session, we just restrict access users based on access rights which are also stored in HttpSession

Comment: It's not the problem, and yes you have to edit the question because SO isn't used for pasting a code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're already capturing the values from `signup.jsp` as instance variables in Action class like below

```
public class SignupAction implements SessionAware{

   private String userid;
   // getters and setters for user id

   // do not create a getter for this
   private Map sessionData;

   public void setSession(Map sessionAttributes){

       this.sessionData = sessionAttributes;
   }

   public String execute(){

    sessionData.put("email",userid);
    // forward to user.jsp
   }

}
```

In you next action class which handles form submit from user.jsp

```
public class UserAction implements SessionAware{

       // do not create a getter for this
       private Map sessionData;

       public void setSession(Map sessionAttributes){

           this.sessionData = sessionAttributes;
       }

       public String execute(){

          if(sessionData.containsKey("email")){
            String email = (String)sessionData.get("email");
            // do what you want with email
          }

       }

    }
```

For more details, you can see this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2203/how-to-get-servlet-session-request-response-context-attributes-in-struts-2-action)

Comment: I want to access the value of userid in the action class of "user.jsp" which is a POJO. So how can I use a struts tag there?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question, I've edited my answer, it should be fine now :)

Comment: Do I need to invalidate the session or something after I've used the value of email for the required purpose?

Comment: We invalidate sessions on logout but usually session will timeout after some time, default is 30 min for tomcat i guess, you can change that to some lower value or even set `MaxInActiveInterval` in web.xml - the maximum time between requests before killing the session. As this is a non-login flow, my advice would be to remove those values from `sessionMap` once you're done using them and let the container take care of killing the session :)